# Cannot debug SharePoint Framework command set extension in Visual Studio Code

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, visual-studio, sharepoint-framework

As mentioned in this guideline I am able to get debugging in VS Code working for a SharePoint Framework web part: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/debug-in-vscode

However command set extensions seem to be a different story. I tried all kinds of debug configurations, but whatever I do the breakpoint in my custom command set extension won't get hit in VS Code.

Seems to me that VS Code debugging in combination with a command set extension is just not possible, or is it ?